# Gallery to display latest image and back/forward buttons to scroll through older images. Jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, gallery

I asked a question earlier, but I think I need a different solution to PHP.

I want to display my latest weathercam image, but have the ability to scroll back through images from throughout the day.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is here:

http://www.ocean-sports.co.uk/ourwebcam/

Can somebody suggest a script that would give me this ability? I've looked everywhere but can't find a good starting point.

Thanks as always.

I should explain the images are uploaded every 2 minutes to a folder on my server space in jpg format.

Comment: Do you have any way for the javascript to query your server for the image list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an endless supply of jQuery image gallery plugins.  Just pick one you like and use it.  Then just write the images to your page ordered by creation date.

Comment: Sorry, so i should be able to do this with any jquery gallery? I'm pretty new to this, so sorry for being stupid

Comment: Yes. If you add the images to the page in date order, they will be displayed by the plugin in date order. If you want thumbnails, search for a "gallery" plugin.  If you don't want thumbnails, an "Image Slider" plugin may better suit your needs.

Comment: Is there also the possibility to add an auto refresh function at the same time? I currently use a single image with a counter refresh function running. A single image is ideal, but just with functionality to scroll back through the images.